# Crypto++ symmetric algorithms and authenticated block modes combinations

Tags: c++, encryption, encryption-symmetric, crypto++, block-cipher

I've implemented a C++ wrapper library for [Crypto++](http://cryptopp.com) v5.6.2 and have a question about combinations of symmetric algorithms (e. g. Blowfish) and block modes (e. g. GCM).

I am able to encrypt and decrypt data via Blowfish/EAX, but I can't achieve the same by using Blowfish/GCM. AES/EAX and AES/GCM both work.

The following simple application demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "cryptopp/blowfish.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/eax.h"
#include "cryptopp/gcm.h"
#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"

std::string encrypt(
    CryptoPP::AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher &encryption,
    std::string const kPlainText,
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock const kKey,
    unsigned const char * kIV) {
  std::string cipher_text;

  // TODO Is this the source of the problem?
  // BlockSize always returns 0 which leads to an exception if GCM block mode is used!
  std::cout << encryption.BlockSize() << " bytes" << std::endl;

  encryption.SetKeyWithIV(
      kKey,
      kKey.size(),
      kIV
  );

  CryptoPP::StringSink *string_sink = new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher_text);
  CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation *transformator = NULL;

  // The AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter adds padding as required.
  transformator = new CryptoPP::AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(
      encryption,
      string_sink);

  bool const kPumpAll = true;
  CryptoPP::StringSource(
      kPlainText,
      kPumpAll,
      transformator);

  return cipher_text;
}

std::string decrypt(
    CryptoPP::AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher &decryption,
    std::string const kCipherText,
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock const kKey,
    unsigned const char * kIV) {
  std::string recovered_plain_text;

  decryption.SetKeyWithIV(
      kKey,
      kKey.size(),
      kIV);

  CryptoPP::StringSink *string_sink = new CryptoPP::StringSink(
      recovered_plain_text);
  CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation *transformator = NULL;
  CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter *decryption_filter = NULL;

  decryption_filter = new CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(
      decryption,
      string_sink);
  transformator = new CryptoPP::Redirector(*decryption_filter);

  bool const kPumpAll = true;
  CryptoPP::StringSource(
      kCipherText,
      kPumpAll,
      transformator);

  return recovered_plain_text;
}

int main() {
  CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
  CryptoPP::SecByteBlock key(CryptoPP::Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
  prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

  byte iv[CryptoPP::Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE];
  prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));

  // Creates templated mode objects of  block ciphers.

  // This works...
//  CryptoPP::EAX<CryptoPP::Blowfish>::Encryption encryption;
//  CryptoPP::EAX<CryptoPP::Blowfish>::Decryption decryption;

  // This does NOT work...
  CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::Blowfish>::Encryption encryption;
  CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::Blowfish>::Decryption decryption;

  std::string plain_text = "Block Mode Test";
  std::string cipher_text = encrypt(encryption, plain_text, key, iv);
  // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidArgument'
  // what():  Blowfish/GCM: block size of underlying block cipher is not 16

  std::cout << "cipher text: " << std::hex << cipher_text << std::endl;
  std::cout << "recovered plain text: " << decrypt(decryption, cipher_text, key, iv) << std::endl;
}
```

A `CryptoPP::InvalidArgument` exception is thrown if running the code above with the following text:

```
Blowfish/GCM: block size of underlying block cipher is not 16
```

But when running the code instead with the block mode EAX, no exception is thrown. So my questions are:

- Does GCM only work with AES? Can GCM also be used with Blowfish or 3DES?
- Is there a matrix available which lists all possible combinations of symmetric algorithms with block modes?
- Or is this a bug in Crypto++? Because the method `BlockSize()` **always** returns `0` but the exception is only raised if using Blowfish (or 3DES) instead of AES. This seems to raise the exception mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

GCM has been designed to work with **128-bit (=16 byte) block size** only. You can find this in the [original paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf) in Section 5.1.

Blowfish is a **64-bit block size** algorithm, so the two are not compatible as an "out-of-the-box" authenticated encryption combination. The same is true for `3DES`. The exception is not a bug in Crypto++.

GCM will work with other Crypto++ objects that have 128-bit block sizes. They include `AES`, `Cast-256`, `Rijndael` `Cameilla`, `MARS`, `Serpent` and `Twofish`. A table of the block sizes is available at [Applied Crypto++: Block Ciphers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21877/Applied-Crypto-Block-Ciphers).

GCM will not work with larger block sizes either. For example, `Rijndael` (the parent of `AES`) offers 192-bit and 256-bit block sizes (`AES` only specifies the 128-bit block size). GCM will not work with the larger block sizes. And the same is true for `SHACAL-2`, with a 256-bit block size.

Crypto++'s `BlockSize()` sometimes returns 0 (it has to do with the template parameters). Instead, use the compile time constants like `AES::BLOCKSIZE`, `Camellia::BLOCKSIZE` and `Rijndael::BLOCKSIZE`. This could be considered a bug.